# Переключатели видимости collapse срабатывают вместе

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Angular 11, имею код:

```
<tbody>
<ul *ngFor="let p of categories; let i = index">
<ng-template [ngIf]="category?.categoryId != p.categoryId"><button mat-raised-button type="button" class="" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"
      [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" aria-controls="collapseExample">{{p.title}} </button> </ng-template> <li> <div id="collapseExample" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
  <p *ngFor="let o of p.subcategories">
      {{o.title}} 
  </p>
</div> </li> </ul> </tbody>
```

И вот что из этого выходит:
[image: категории]

Т.е. когда нажимаю на любую категорию, то раскрываются все подкатегории всех категорий. Как исправить?

Comment: нужно либо хранить список флагов Collapsed, либо хранить не boolean, а раскрытый объект

Comment: А можно пример хотя бы одного из вариантов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, можно завести Map в котором хранить состояние подраздела:

```
<tbody>

  <ul *ngFor="let p of categories; let i = index">

    <ng-template [ngIf]="category?.categoryId != p.categoryId">
      <button mat-raised-button type="button" class="" (click)="collapse(p)"
      [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed(p)" aria-controls="collapseExample">{{p.title}}     
      </button> 
    </ng-template> 

    <li> 
      <div id="collapseExample" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed(p)">
        <p *ngFor="let o of p.subcategories">
          {{o.title}} 
        </p>
      </div> 
    </li>

  </ul> 
</tbody>
```

ts:

```
collapses = new Map<string, bool>();

collapse(category: string): void {
    this.collapses.set(category, !this.collapses.get(category));
}

isCollapsed(category: string): boolean {
    return this.collapses.get(category);
}
```

Либо завести Array/Set в который добавлять/удалять подраздел:

```
collapses = new Set<string>();

collapse(category: string): void {
    if (this.collapses.has(category))
        this.collapses.delete(category);
    else
        this.collapses.set(category);
}

isCollapsed(category: string): boolean {
    return this.collapses.has(category);
}
```